# How to count each of the occurrences of a term PER DOCUMENT in apache SOLR?

Tags: apache, http, solr

Good! I need to get the number of occurrences of a search term for each document stored in Solr (I have indexed "PDF" documents).
That is, if you have the following information:

- document A: 3 times the word "house" appears.
- document B: the word "house" appears 4 times.
- document C: the word "house" appears 1 times.

So, if I search for "house", I need to obtain that for document A it appears 3 times, for B 4 times and for C 1 time. And in total 8 times (3 + 4 + 1). How can I do this in a query from HTTP, that is "'http: // localhost: 8983 / solr / ......."?
Thank you very much, Regards.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you indexed the whole document into one field (e.g. text). In which case, you can use a [Function Query termfreq](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/function-queries.html#termfreq-function) to return number of times your term shows up in that field.

There are several ways to use a function query, including using it as a pseudo-field by just putting it in the **fl** field list:

[http://localhost:8983/solr/**corename**/select?fl=*,termfreq(text,"house")&q=house](http://localhost:8983/solr/dip/select?fl=*,%20termfreq(text,%27house%27)&q=house)